# Sencha Touch - components from "requires" not loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got form for signin in app/form/signIn.js

```
Ext.define('app.form.signIn', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Password'
    ],
    config: {
      ...
    }
});
```

And view, that requires and use this form.

```
Ext.define('app.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    alias: 'widget.View',
    requires: [
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'app.form.signIn',
        'app.form.signUp'
    ],
    config: {
        'id':'viewMain',
        items: [
           Ext.create('app.form.signIn')
           ....
        ]
    }
});
```

Form is defined in requires section of View. But I still see in browser message

> [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading
>   'app.form.signIn'; consider adding
>   'app.form.signIn' explicitly as a require of the
>   corresponding class

1. How should I define the require to load automatically?
2. Buttons on the form works as expected in dev mode. But after the build - there are not handlers from the controller for the buttons on this form. May it be caused by "require" error?

Thank you very much for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never give it a chance to process the requires block. You're essentially requiring it, then forcing it to load synchronously in the same block.

Use the config:

```
Ext.define('app.form.signIn', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    xtype: 'signinform'
});

// Define it

items: [{
    xtype: 'signinform'
}]
```